# Expression cannot be evaluated. in SSIS (IDTSVariableDispenser100 vars, Boolean isSensitive)

Tags: ssis

[image]

Attempt to parse the expression "@[User::IncrementVal]==1? @[User::SrcFolderCases]: @[User::SrcFolderAdd]: @[User::SrcFolderDeath]" failed. The expression might contain an invalid token, an incomplete token, or an invalid element. It might not be well-formed, or might be missing part of a required element such as a parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax of SSIS [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) is the following

```
boolean_expression?expression1:expression2
```

In your case, the third variable after `:`, i.e. `@[User::SrcFolderDeath]` makes the expression void. Either remove it or transform with concatenation with other variable, for example.

Comment: Hi Mate, Still getting same error after I corrected the expression using ":" Here it is
@[User::IncrementVal]==1 ?  @[User::SrcFileCases] : @[User::SrcFileAdd] : @[User::SrcFileDeath]

Comment: @PSudarsan, in your expression, the last variable making it not valid. Example of valid conditional expression - `@[User::IncrementVal]==1 ? @[User::SrcFileCases] : @[User::SrcFileAdd]` which means - return `SrcFileCases` if `IncrementInterval`==1, else `SrcFileAdd`.  Please write in the message what you are trying to achieve by this conditional operator.

Comment: I am getting error on when i try to do @[User::IncrementVal]==1?

Comment: Please provide the error message for expression `@[User::IncrementVal]==1 ? 1 : 0`. What is data type of `IncrementVal` variable?